# Paypal Settlement Reports not working

Tags: paypal, reports

Settlement Reports returns that it fetched n rows, but nothing populates on Magento Side.

Was running Magento 1.9 and updated to 1.9.1.0 to the same effect.

Comment: I have been fighting with this for many hours. See [this][1]

  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/magento-not-fetching-paypal-settlement-reports/64498

Answer (score 0):

Magento's documentation on Paypal Settlement Reports is almost nonexistent.

Not sure how many people use this report as there is nothing on the web on this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-set-up-and-run-paypal-settlement-reports doesn't mention anything about all the versions available of the Paypal Reports.

Paypal Settlement Report is now on version 8.0, but on the Payapal SFTP report subscriptions you cannot easily change the versions. My paypal was set up for version 1.0 and I managed to change to version 7 without talking to the customer support by unsubscribing the report and resubscribing. When you re-subscribe, the newer version started being pushed.

Since the reports are pushed once a day, you need to wait for the new version to be available on SFTP.

Magento was still failing after the update to version 7

I'm not sure about other versions, but version 7 has an error in the STL reports where
Transaction Debit or Credit header has 2 spaces between Transaction and Debit, and Magento fails the import.

To fix it, you need to change 
 /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php and add the extra space for that header.

all good now.

Pedro

Comment: Instead of editing the file, create an extension that will handle the change you require. Or at the least override into local. I suggest however adding this into the bug tracker so a future patch may be released or included in the core. http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking