# Magento not fetching PayPal Settlement reports

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, reports

I have properly set PayPal settlement reports - username, pass, everything.

When in Magento's admin panel I go to **Reports > Sales > PayPal Settlement Reports** and click **Fetch Updates** in `var/log/system.log` I see these messages (actually much more then these but with the same pattern):

```
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: TransactionID  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: InvoiceID  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: PayPalReferenceID  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: PayPalReferenceIDType  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: TransactionEventCode  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: TransactionInitiationDate  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: TransactionCompletionDate  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: TransactionDebitOrCredit  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: GrossTransactionAmount  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: GrossTransactionCurrency  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: FeeDebitOrCredit  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: FeeAmount  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: FeeCurrency  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: CustomField  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: ConsumerID  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
2015-04-22T15:46:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: PaymentTrackingID  in /www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Report/Settlement.php on line 301
```

and in the web interface of the admin panel I get a green ("succesful") message

> Fetched 0 report rows from '...myusername@reports.paypal.com'

I have tried to debug the code but all I see on **line 301** is:

```
$bodyItem[$rowMap[$flippedSectionColumns[$i]]] = $line[$i];
```

and I can't understand what is the problem. It seems ok at first glance.

I have tripple checked and debugged - **the CSV files get properly downloaded from PayPal** and the $line array is filled up with values. Still I am getting this error and the data is not fetched into Magento.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the 301 line and the array of rows seems to be filled in correctly:

```
$bodyItem[$flippedSectionColumns[$i]] = $line[$i];
```

But this is a bug in Magento and will never work until they fix also the `_beforesave()` method which seems to be referencing non-existing methods and never returns `true` in order to save the data in Magento.

[Reported](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/717).